# One submit button for Form and textbox MVC4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, view

I am using MVC4.

I have view of form using @using (Html.BeginForm)
But I want to use **table** instead of **fieldset**

The view look great but then I had to have the submit button (in every record)as shown in my code .

1. I want only **one button to submit** ? So I try to put the submit out
   of (Html.BeginForm) but then  it will not work!!?
2. Also I have textbox for price ...And I want to be linked to the **same submit button**

this is my view :

```
<p>Enter the price please :</p>@Html.TextBox("price")
   <fieldset> 
     <legend></legend>
   <table>
     <tr>
        <th>
           Title1
        </th>
        <th>
           Title1 
        </th>
        <th>
           Title3 
        </th>
        <th>
           button
        </th>
     </tr>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Contrroler"))
  { 

int index = 0;


        foreach (var req in Model.SelectedHome.Descreption)
        {               
             <tr>
             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.homenmae)

            </td> 

             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.place)

            </td> 
             <td>
                 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.rommsnumber)

            </td> 
             <td>
                 <button type="submit" class="button "> click </button>
             <td>
                </tr> 


            index++;
        }

 } 
 </table>


 </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't submit a form with submit button out of form without some additional code

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Contrroler", FormMethod.Post, new {id='myForm'} ))
          { 

<p>Enter the price please :</p>@Html.TextBox("price")
   <fieldset> 
     <legend></legend>
   <table>
     <tr>
        <th>
           Title1
        </th>
        <th>
           Title1 
        </th>
        <th>
           Title3 
        </th>
        <th>
           button
        </th>
     </tr>



        int index = 0;


                foreach (var req in Model.SelectedHome.Descreption)
                {               
                     <tr>
                     <td>
                         @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.homenmae)

                    </td> 

                     <td>
                         @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.place)

                    </td> 
                     <td>
                         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.rommsnumber)

                    </td> 

                 </tr> 

                    index++;
                }
        }
    </table>

    <button id='submitForm'>Submit</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#submitForm').click(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

Comment: ok..but what about the textbox? i need to use the same button

Comment: so you should to add the textbox into your form. check the updated code in the answer.

Comment: I change 'myForm' to "myForm" & id='submitForm' to id="submitForm".....the button is not working!!

Comment: there's an example with submitting form with button out of form: http://jsfiddle.net/cw9tF/ . Notice that it uses jQuery code, that must run after page or elements loaded

Comment: Does signature of your action method at which your form links contains textBox value?

Comment: If you cannot pass textBox value to action, you should create a ViewModel that will contain your model and textBox value as fields. Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BdJUWs

Comment: no the problem is with the view code not from controller side  ,coz i try to have 2 button and it work.

Answer (score 0):

Put the submit button outside the for loop but within the form

Comment: ok..but what about the textbox? i need to use the same button

Comment: begin your form above the textbox and then it will be submitted also